# Visual Studio Extensions - How to create a SolutionFolder inside a SolutionFolder?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, envdte

According to what I can find [here](https://www.mztools.com/articles/2011/MZ2011002.aspx) it is not possible to add a SolutionFolder inside a SolutionFolder:

> Visual Studio 2005 and higher allows you to add folders to the
>   solution (which are called solution folders), not only to add folders
>   to a project (something that was already allowed by Visual Studio .NET
>   2002). Solution folders can be nested, and a folder that belongs to
>   the solution (a root solution folder) is modeled as an EnvDTE.Project,
>   so to add a child solution folder to a root solution folder you have
>   to use the EnvDTE.Project.ProjectItems.AddFolder method. However, this
>   method causes a NotImplementedException.

I am trying to do the same thing now - 7 years after the writing of that blogpost, in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.8.4 - and unfortunately, I get the same NotImplementedException when trying this.

Is there any other possible way of creating such a sub-solution-folder from a Visual Studio Extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Visual Studio Extensions - How to create a SolutionFolder inside a SolutionFolder?

Here is a extension about how to create a Solution Folder from a selected folder also including the files in that selected folder: [Folder To Solution Folder](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=CeciliaWiren-CeciliaSHARP.FolderToSolutionFolder).

> Remove the hassle of adding several files to solution folder. Just use
>   the context menu for the solution and just below the option of
>   creating a new solution folder you now find 'Add Folder as Solution
>   Folder'. This will create a solution folder with the same name as you
>   selected and add the items inside of that folder to the solution
>   folder. This will not move the files on disk.

You can check the source code from: https://github.com/ceciliasharp/Extension.FolderToSolutionFolder

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That was a great help and exactly what I needed! I'm going to post the actual code as an answer as well, just in case that Github solution ever disappears...

Answer (score 1):

So, it appears the trick is to get the SolutionFolder in which you want to create the subfolder as a *EnvDTE.Project*, then get its *Object* property and cast that as a *SolutionFolder*.

That will give you an object on which you can call "AddSolutionFolder" with a foldername.

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;

Solution2 solution = (Solution2)dte.Solution;

// Adds a SolutionFolder (in the standard way) underneath the Solution and returns
// a Project. That Project object is the same as what you would get when going
// over your solution with solution.Projects and getting the folder you need
Project solutionFolderAsProject = solution.AddSolutionFolder(folder.Name);

SolutionFolder solutionFolderAsSolutionFolder = (SolutionFolder)solutionFolderAsProject.Object;

Project subSolutionFolder = solutionFolderAsSolutionFolder.AddSolutionFolder(item.Name);
```